# Почему нужно писать кавычки чтобы печатать несколько строк в аргументах discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Например, если я ввожу в аргументы функции вот эту строку:

```
Я

Люблю

Стек
```

Выводится только "Я"

Как это решить без того, чтобы писать `Я Люблю Стек` без кавычек?

Пример кода:

```
    async def report(ctx, type__ = None, text = None):
        embed_obj = discord.Embed()
        embed_obj.description = f'Ваша заявка с текстом {text} успешно зарегестрирована! Мы обязательно её рассмотрим.'
        embed_obj.title = '**Сообщение отправлено**'
        embed_obj.colour = config.green
await ctx.send(embed=embed_obj)
```

Вывод этой команды

```
!report баг Какой то

баг

Здесь

Результат - "Какой то"
```

Comment: можете пример показать?

Comment: Поправил тему...

Comment: Это явно не вывод команды код которой вы привели

Comment: Это именно так почему то и работает...